# lapply is very slow, is there a faster way?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a rather large dataset organized in a list like so:

```
set.seed(0)
v <- rnorm(5000)
names(v) <- seq(1001, 6000, 1)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date('2023-01-01'), by='day', length.out=365)
ls <- list()
ls <- sapply(dates, function(d) {ls[[length(ls) + 1]] <- v; ls})
names(ls) <- dates
str(ls[1:5])

List of 5
 $ 2023-01-01: Named num [1:5000] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5000] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-02: Named num [1:5000] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5000] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-03: Named num [1:5000] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5000] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-04: Named num [1:5000] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5000] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-05: Named num [1:5000] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5000] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
```

As you can see, this is 5000 data points for each day of the year totaling 1,825,000 data points. Let's call them "x". I want to perform the following operation on EACH data point, x: max(c(0.5 - x, 0)). The following code works but takes a really long time.

```
new <- sapply(names(ls), function(d)
          lapply(names(v), function(n) max(c(0.5 - ls[[d]][n], 0))))
rownames(new) <- names(v)
new[1:5, 1:5]

     2023-01-01 2023-01-02 2023-01-03 2023-01-04 2023-01-05
1001 0          0          0          0          0         
1002 0.8262334  0.8262334  0.8262334  0.8262334  0.8262334 
1003 0          0          0          0          0         
1004 0          0          0          0          0         
1005 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
m <- 0.5 - do.call(cbind, ls)
m[m < 0] <- 0
```

Which gives:

```
head(m, c(5,5))

     2023-01-01 2023-01-02 2023-01-03 2023-01-04 2023-01-05
1001 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
1002 0.82623336 0.82623336 0.82623336 0.82623336 0.82623336
1003 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
1004 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
1005 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857 0.08535857
```

Benchmarks:

```
bench::mark(a = sapply(ls, \(v) pmax(0.5 - v, 0)),
            b = {
              m <- do.call(cbind, ls)
              pmax(0.5 - m, 0)
            },
            c = {
              m <- 0.5 - do.call(cbind, ls)
              m[m < 0] <- 0
              m
            })

# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory             time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>             <list>     <list>  
1 a           247.6ms    248ms      4.04     305MB     4.04     1     1      248ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem>         <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 b           113.1ms    114ms      8.77     229MB     0        5     0      570ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem [4 × 3]> <bench_tm> <tibble>
3 c            99.5ms    106ms      9.16     165MB     0        5     0      546ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem [5 × 3]> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Comment: WOW! I wish I could mark both Hugh's and your answer as correct. Both have opened up my eyes. I have never even seen the \ operator before. I have often also mused over what good the pmax/pmin functions are. Now, I have a use. There is a lot to digest here and clearly much of it falls into best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of applying lapply, use `pmax`

```r
new <- sapply(ls, \(v) pmax(0.5 - v, 0))
```

Comment: Better to column bind the list into a matrix and then use pmax than to iterate over it.

Comment: Hugh, that is several orders of magnitude faster which is really cool. However, is there a way to do that using the list, "ls" and not "v"? My actual data only consists of ls, and every day is actually different unlike this example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @WishIaskedThisSooner - `v` is just the name of the argument to the function, not your `v` object. It could be `x` or `y` or anything. This code is looping over `ls`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have never seen the \ operator before and it confused me. I assume it is just shorthand for function(v). I tried googling it but nothing came up.

Comment: @WishIaskedThisSooner - yep, just a shortcut for function - it came in to R back in mid-2021 (R 4.1)